# Passar id de um dado de uma tabela para a modal?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia pessoal, para um trabalho da faculdade estou tentando criar uma modal, para decisão se eu quero ou não excluir um registro de uma tabela, nesta tabela eu tenho as informações do usuário em uma grid com botoes de new, delete, edit e checkbox para remoção de vários registros. Nos botoes eu tenho a informação do id nas tags  com a referencia dos mesmos para a janela de cadastro do usuario.

no momento do click gostaria de chamar a modal para confirmar a exclusão ou cancelar a operação. Mas não sei como passar um id que está na referencia do mesmo para ela. Ou outra forma que funcione.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Usuários</title>

        <?php
        include_once './menu_logged.php';
        include_once './_dao/dao_usuario.php';

//        $key = "38ea2ab716998d19"; //Gimenes
//        $aes = new AES($key);
        ?>

        <!-- IMPORTAÇÕES PARA A TABELA EM CSS -->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "_css/table_white_normalize.css">
        <link rel = 'stylesheet prefetch' href = '_css/dataTables.white.bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet prefetch' href = '_css/dataTables.white.responsive.css'>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "_css/table_white.css">       
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "_css/checkbox_black.css">       
        <!-- FIM IMPORTAÇÕES PARA A TABELA EM CSS -->
 
        <script>
            function newDoc() {
                window.location.assign("tb_users.php");
            }
            document.onkeyup = function (e) {
                if (e.which === 46) {
                    document.formSubmit.submit();
                    return false;
                }
            };            
        </script>

        <style>
            div{
                font-family: Ubuntu-L;
            }
            div#extTable{
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px silver; 
                padding: 20px; 
                background-color: white
            }
            h2{
                font-family: Ubuntu-M;
            }
            .pagination > .active > a,
            .pagination > .active > span,
            .pagination > .active > a:hover,
            .pagination > .active > span:hover,
            .pagination > .active > a:focus,
            .pagination > .active > span:focus {
                z-index: 3;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: default;
                /*background-color: #337ab7;*/ 
                /*INICIO D ALTERAÇÃO DO BOOTSTRAP COLOR*/
                color:white !important;
                border:1px solid #111;
                background-color:#585858;
                background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111));
                background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);
                background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);
                background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);
                background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);
                background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111 100%);
                /*FIM DA ALTERAÇÃO DO BOOTSTRAP COLOR*/
                border-color: silver;
            }        
            .pagination > li > a,
            .pagination > li > span {
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                padding: 6px 12px;
                margin-left: -1px;
                line-height: 1.42857143;
                color: #337ab7;
                color: #585858;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
            }           
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="container">

            <!-- INICIO / FORM PARA A CAPTAÇÃO DA TECLA DEL -->
            <form action="#" method="post" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit"> 

                <h2 style="text-align: left;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Usuários</h2>

                <!-- INICIO QUADRO EXTERNO PARA A TABELA-->
                <div id="extTable">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                            <!-- INICIO DA TABELA -->
                            <table summary="This table shows how to create responsive tables using Datatables' extended functionality" class="table-responsive table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                                <caption class="text-left" hidden>Usuários cadastrados no sistema.</caption>

                                <?php
                                /* #INICIO - Var de Mensagens para as modais */
                                $msgModal = "";
                                $linhaModal = "";
                                /* #FIM */

                                /* #INICIO - Método de checagem de registros selecionados para exclusão simultanea */
                                if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
                                    try {
                                        if (!DaoUsuario::deleteSelected($_POST['check'])) {
                                            $msgModal = "Não foi possivel excluir os registros selecionados !";
                                            $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';
                                            echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                        } else {
                                            $msgModal = "Os usuários selecionados foram removidos com sucesso !";
                                            $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: green"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';
                                            echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                        }
                                    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                                        $msgModal = "Conflito na remoção dos registros selecionados. ERRO --> " . $ex->getMessage();
                                        $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';
                                        echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                    }
                                }
                                /* #FIM - método de checagem de registros selecionados para exclusão simultanea */

                                /* #INICIO - Método de exclusão de registro */
                                if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
                                    try {
                                        if (!DaoUsuario::delete($_GET['id'])) {
                                            $msgModal = "Não foi possivel excluir o registro selecionado !";
                                            $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';
                                            echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                        } else {
                                            $msgModal = "O usuário selecionado foi removido com sucesso !";
                                            $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color: green"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';

                                            echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                        }
                                    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                                        $msgModal = "Conflito na remoção do registro selecionado. ERRO --> " . $ex->getMessage();
                                        $linhaModal = '<p style="text-align: center;"><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red"></span> &nbsp; ' . $msgModal . ' </b></p>';
                                        echo '<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#modalUser").modal(); }); </script>';
                                    }
                                }/* #FIM - Método de exclusão  de registro */
                                ?>

                                <!-- ININIO / THEAD (CABEÇA) da tabela -->
                                <thead>                           
                                    <?php
                                    /* #INICIO - Consulta no banco de dados */
                                    $user_array = DaoUsuario::selectAll();
                                    /* #FIM - Consulta no banco de dados */

                                    /* #INICIO - Construção do cabeçalho da tabela */
                                    echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<th id="id"></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;#</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="nm"></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;NOME</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="lgn"></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;LOGIN</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="nivel"></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;NÍVEL</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="img"></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;IMAGEM</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="opc">OPÇÕES</th>';
                                    echo '<th id="check"></th>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                    /* #FIM - Construção do cabeçalho da tabela */
                                    ?>                            
                                </thead>
                                <!-- FIM / THEAD (CABEÇA) da tabela -->

                                <!-- INICIO / BODY da tabela -->
                                <tbody> 
                                    <?php
                                    /* #INICIO - Geração das linhas da tabela utilizando um vetor recebido pela consulta no banco */
                                    foreach ($user_array as $row) {
                                        echo '<tr id='.base64_encode($row->getId_usuario()).'>';
                                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">' . $row->getId_usuario() . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">' . $row->getNm_usuario() . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">' . $row->getNm_login() . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">' . $row->getTp_usuario() . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="' . $row->getImg_link() . '" width="30" heigth="30"/></td>';
                                        echo '<td style="width: 40px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="form_usuario.php"><button type="button" title="Novo Usuário" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"><span></button></a> &nbsp;'
                                        . '<a href="tb_users.php?id=' . base64_encode($row->getId_usuario()) . '&ex=true"><button type="button" title="Remover Usuário" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"><span></button></a> &nbsp;'
                                        . '<a href="form_usuario.php?id=' . base64_encode($row->getId_usuario()) . '"><button type="button" title="Alterar Usuário"class="btn btn-inverse"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"><span></button></a></td>';
                                        echo "<td style='width: 40px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'><input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='" . base64_encode($row->getId_usuario()) . "' /></td>";
                                        echo '</tr>';
                                    }
                                    /* #FIM - Construção do cabeçalho da tabela */
                                    ?>                               
                                </tbody>
                                <!-- FIM / BODY da tabela -->

                                <!-- INICIO / Footer da tabela -->
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">** Para remover um ou mais registros selecione as caixas de marcação e tecle DEL.</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                                <!-- FIM - Footer da tabela -->

                            </table>
                            <!-- FIM DA TABELA -->
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <!-- FIM QUADRO EXTERNO PARA A TABELA-->
            </form>
            <!-- FIM / FORM PARA A CAPTAÇÃO DA TECLA DEL -->
        </div>    

        <br>
        <br> 

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="modalUser" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Remoção de Usuário</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php echo $linhaModal; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="newDoc()">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <!-- IMPORTAÇÃO DOS SCRIPTS JS PARA A TABELA -->
        <script src='_js/jquery.dataTables.table_white.js'></script>;
        <script src='_js/dataTables.white.bootstrap.js'></script>
        <script src='_js/dataTables.white.responsive.js'></script>
        <script src="_js/table_white.js"></script>
        <!-- FIM DA IMPORTAÇÃO DOS SCRIPTS JS PARA A TABELA -->

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Não vai funcionar a execução porque precisa das dependências, caso precisem posso mandar o projeto.

Obrigado..

---

Gostaria de agradecer a todos que se disponibilizaram a me ajudar perante a minha dúvida. Principalmente o usuário **Miguel** que me acompanhou durante o dia.. Muito obrigado.....

Comment: A modal não está pronta... Ainda preciso modificar o meio e adicinar os botoes.. seria a modaUser...

Comment: Peço-lhe que acrescente as tags, boostrap e jquery. Porque na realidade isto não é feito em php...

Comment: Perdão pessoal esta e a modal só para mensagens de confirmação da operação que já aconteceu, eu criaria uma outra, com os botoes de cancelamento e confirmação por ex. uma modalQuestion...

Comment: Sim vou adicionar desculpe..

Comment: Sem problema. A resposta em baixo não ajuda nisso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo que creio que conseguirá ajustar ao que quer. O que fiz foi para cada botão apagar na tabela adicionar atributos [data de html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), é mesmo muito util nestas situações, pode retirar o `data-name` se não precisar de incluir na pergunta de confirmação da modal:

Observe os `hrefs` do botão Sim da modal a mudarem consoante o elemento da tebela onde clicou para apagar.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2pmn1ems/22/)

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function(){
      var nome = $(this).data('nome'); // vamos buscar o valor do atributo data-name que temos no botão que foi clicado
      var id = $(this).data('id'); // vamos buscar o valor do atributo data-id
      $('span.nome').text(nome+ ' (id = ' +id+ ')'); // inserir na o nome na pergunta de confirmação dentro da modal
      $('a.delete-yes').attr('href', 'apagar.php?id=' +id); // mudar dinamicamente o link, href do botão confirmar da modal
      $('#myModal').modal('show'); // modal aparece
});
```

```css
td {
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
nome1
  </td>
  <td>
telefone1
  </td>
  <td>
email1
  </td>
  <td>
endereço1
  </td>
  <td><button data-nome="nome1" data-id="1" class="delete btn btn-xs btn-primary">Apagar</button>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
nome2
  </td>
  <td>
telefone2
  </td>
  <td>
email2
  </td>
  <td>
endereço2
  </td>
  <td><button data-nome="nome2" data-id="2" class="delete btn btn-xs btn-primary">Apagar</button>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
nome3
  </td>
  <td>
telefone3
  </td>
  <td>
email3
  </td>
  <td>
endereço3
  </td>
  <td><button data-nome="nome3" data-id="3" class="delete btn btn-xs btn-primary">Apagar</button>
  </td>
</tr>

</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      Deseja mesmo apagar <span class="nome"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default delete-yes">Sim</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</button>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lógica é simples, recupere o ID do registro e passe para o seu modal usando [set Attributes - attr() do jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp).
Aqui nesse exemplo eu pessei o valor do id para o atributo classe do modal.
Para guardar o ID do registro vc pode fazer de algumas maneiras diferentes quando estiver gerando a página com o php.
Eu geralmente guardo como id no elemento tr. Ou seja, aquela linha pertence a um registro specífico. Entáo vc recupera o id da linha e passa para o modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#seuBtnDeletar").click(function(){
        //Recupere o Id do registro e passe para o seu modal
        var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
        $("#meuModal").attr("class", trid );
    });
});
```

No código, `$(this).` é o botão, e `closest('tr').attr('id');` recupera o id do tr no qual o botao esta inserido. Vc pode usar uma string composta para guardar o id do elemento `<tr>`

Comment: Eu vou adicionar um id="id do registro" ao <tr>, retirar o <a href=""> do botão, e adicionar o código do jquery. alterando o id para nome do meu botao, e o nome da minha modal... É isso, desculpe não consegui fazer funcionar, ainda estou aprendendo tem menos de um mês mexendo com php.

Comment: Isso. Eu geralmente faço assim: `<tr id="id_2" ...>`. Depois recupera e trata a string para identificar o id do registro. Tem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Uma outra abordagem, a que eu acho mais simples, é deixar o modal já pronto, quando vc gerar a página dinamicamente com o php. Ou seja, se vc inspecionar o código fonte da página, vai ver que todos os modais já estáo lá. Não vai precisar de javascript para passar nada para eles. Obviamente isso tem limite. Depende da sua análise. Vou editar minha resposta para clarificar.